# how to disable one button but not all in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, button, jbutton, actionlistener

I have one actionListener attached to all my Buttons. I have 26 buttons each corresponding to one alphabet. After an alphabet is clicked, I want to disable that button alone. how can I achieve this Jwing?
I am pasting a part of code, as my entire is too long and has other details which are not necessary.
Thanks

```
public DetailsPanel(GuessPane guess) {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" click here "));

            JPanel letterPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 5));
            for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
                String buttonText = String.valueOf(alphabet);
                JButton letterButton = new JButton(buttonText);
                letterButton.addActionListener(clickedbutton(guess));
                letterPanel.add(letterButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
            add(letterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        private ActionListener clickedbutton(final GuessPane guess) {
            return new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JButton pressedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("actionCommand is: ---" + actionCommand);
                        guess.setLetter(actionCommand);
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: pressedButton.setEnabled(false) in your ActionListener ???

Comment: @Stanislav Mamontov What he is really asking is how to detect which button fired the event

Comment: yes, detect which button fired the event and then disable only that

Comment: @user1988876, Stanislav has already given you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the source of the event by using `event.getSource()` (and `notice getSource()` returns an `Object` so you need to cast it aswell):

```
((AbstractButton)event.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Or you could simply disable the source. `((AbstractButton)event.getSource()).setEnabled(false);` 1+

Comment: -1, you already know the source because you got the source button from the ActionEvent. So why do you need to compare the source to other buttons?

Comment: @camickr yes sorry I forgot what the question was for a sec